# Passing int to a function which accepts int64 as input parameter

Tags: c

I have a function that accepts pointer to int64 and prints the value. Now if I pass an integer from the calling function, it gives the original value plus gives extra 4 bytes as it is an int64 and am passing integer. How do I take care of this so that if I pass an integer to the function which accepts int64, still an integer value gets printed.

```
void foo(int64_t * temp) // just mentioning a simplified function
{
    printf("%llx\n",*temp); 
}
```

If I try to pass an integer with value "0x12345678" then the value that foo function prints out is "xxxxxxxx12345678" where xxx are garbage values.

Update:
I can do this by using a temp int64 variable/pointer and pass it but I don't or rather can't do that, is there any other way?

Comment: I always love it when people post questions here and then reject the proper answer preemptively. "And please don't tell me the right way to do this, 'cause I don't want that. Please give me a kludgy, poor hacky way to do it instead."

Comment: well thats what I have been telling the person who has asked me this question but he says there is way so thought of asking this to SO community.

Comment: I think you need to explain the actual problem so we can help you with an actual solution to it, rather than asking about something unrelated and getting answers that may have nothing to do with your actual problem.

Comment: True, apologies for asking it pre-medatively, I myself dont have much idea about the exact situation as I myself am trying to understand the problem. Will try to delete the post if possible. Thanks for your answers any ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you typecast something to fake out the compiler, then all bets are off.  Undefined behaviour and all that jazz.  To fix it, create an appropriate variable and call your function with it instead:

```
int32_t x = 0x12345678;
int64_t y = x;

foo(&y);
```

Edit:  You say you "don't or rather can't" make this change, but you'll have to if you want it to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer Carl but I want a way without the above approach. Forgot to mention in my question and have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: And I've updated my answer.  You can't.  Why can't you do it the right way?

Comment: Because the scenario involves similar representations at a lot of places and can't afford this method at various places because of memory and other constraints and hence want some other way.

More importantly, this is the restriction that has been given to me by my superior :).

Comment: There are likely no significant "memory or other constraints" involved with doing it the right way.  Can you explain your actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no - your function requires a pointer to a 64 bit value and such a pointer you must give it.

Note, however, that there is no reason in the example to pass a pointer at all - why not pass the argument by value, whereby any integer type up to 64 bits will be accepted?

```
void foo(int64_t temp)
{
    printf("%llx\n",temp); 
}
```

Comment: The function is going to modify the variable, I just mentioned a simplified function :)

Comment: Then you must pass exactly the pointer required.  In this case, though, can you not return the modified value?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do it in many places, you could create a wrapper function which does the said job for you, such as

```
void foo_i64(int64_t * temp) // your original function
{
    // do stuff with that pointer
}

void foo_i(int * temp) // wrapper function
{
    int64_t t2 = *temp; // copy value
    foo_i64(&t2);
    *temp = t2; // copy value back to where we need it. There might be an overflow!
}
```

Now you can use that wrapper function `foo_i()` wherever you have an `int` variable to be modified/processed.